# How to sync motion and music in After Effects

Tags: after-effects, sync, motion, music

- There's a video of a man, drawing something.
- There's a violin symphony music.

I want to sync the video, I mean the movements of hand with the symphony.

For example, I want the hand to move fast, when the music rate is fast, etc.

What I have to look for to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on **how much time stretch is key** to synchronize the shot.

1. In order to increase the speed of the whole layer use the **Time Stretch** feature (*Right Click the Layer > Time > Time Stretch*) *Note: values below 100 increase the speed. Values above 110 often results in bad quality. To solve this, see motion calculation (3.)*
2. To vary the speed of a layer, it's ok in most cases to use the standard **Time Remapping** feature (*Right Click the Layer > Time > Enable Time Remapping*) This makes it possible to keyframe the time/speed of your layer.
3. In some situations, especially for generating slow motion shots you need to **calculate the motion in between the frames** with [optical flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_flow) technology like [twixtor](http://www.revisionfx.com/products/twixtor/). You can also play with [**SlomoVideo**](https://github.com/slowmoVideo/slowmoVideo/) as an open source alternative. For further information, see this article: http://www.fxguide.com/featured/art_of_optical_flow/

---

For **audio preview workflow**, see: [How can I preview with audio in After Effects and be able to pause / resume the preview?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15319/how-can-i-preview-with-audio-in-after-effects-and-be-able-to-pause-resume-the/15321#15321)